# Does anyone have a clue how to solve this second-order homogenous linear ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This example is provided by my workbook and it specifically asked to solve the equation via a substitution.

$$y'' + 2xy' - 2y=0$$.

What I have tried is the substitution $y=u(x) \cdot z, z(x)$ which yields absolutely no answer, because I get a harder ODE to solve than the first one:

$$z'' + (-x^3-3)z=0$$

Right now, there's no apparent substitution to be done. I suspect it has something to do with the coefficient $2x$ but I don't have the knowledge to actually do a substitution and solve it.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Try the substitution $y=e^{ax}$. Of course, since this is homogenous, multiples of any solution by constants are also solutions.

Comment: Your transformed equation should be $z''-(x^2+3)z=0$, there should be no cubic exponent.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks for correcting my mistake! The solution of that equation is, sadly, expressed in the terms of some non-standard functions which makes me think there must be another substitution.

Answer (score 2):

The last two terms, as any multiple of $(xy'-y)$, cancel for $y=ax$, the second derivative is then zero too.

A second basis solution will then have the form $y(x)=xz(x)$, inserting gives
$$
0=[xz''+2z']+2x[xz'+z]-2xz=xz''+2(1+x^2)z'
$$
which is separable and solvable as
$$
z'=\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2}
$$
fixing the integration constant. Now continue using partial integration
$$
\left(z+\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x}\right)'=-2\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x}\\
\left(z+\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x}+2\ln|x|e^{-x^2}\right)'=-4x\ln|x|e^{-x^2}\\
$$
where the right side is now a continuous function,...